# org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException at CompositeMigrationResolver.java:147

Tags: java, kotlin, flyway, spring-boot-test

The following error has occurred:

```
org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException at CompositeMigrationResolver.java:147.
```

This error is occurring on Github Actions.

Please note that we are using Flyway version 6.4.0, and from what we can see in [the source code](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/blob/flyway-6.4.0/flyway-core/src/main/java/org/flywaydb/core/internal/resolver/CompositeMigrationResolver.java#L147), it appears to be an error that occurs when versions are duplicated.（This is just my opinion, so I can't guarantee it's correct but...）

Of course, I've checked the migration files and confirmed that the versions are not duplicated.

In addition, this error occurs when tests fail in @SpringBootTest. The error logs output for each failed test are as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException at DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:132
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException at AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException at NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:-2
Caused by: org.flywaydb.core.api.FlywayException at CompositeMigrationResolver.java:147"
```

Would anyone happen to know something about this error? I would greatly appreciate it if someone who understands could respond.

Answer (score 0):

New migration files were committed to my remote base branch, but I was unaware of this. As a result, my branch's migration file and the base branch's migration file are now in conflict.